# Angular 1.6.6 and uib-typeahead not working good

Tags: angularjs

I have the following problem. I moved on Angular 1.6.6 from 1.4.8.

```html
<input type="select" class="form-control pull-right"
  placeholder="Enter IPC or Project Reference" ng-model="systemState.quickSearchTerm"
  uib-typeahead-on-select="selectQuickSearchResult($item)"
  uib-typeahead="result.display for result in quickSearchResults"
  ng-change="quickSearch()" uib-typeahead-wait-ms="200" ng-model-options="{debounce: 500}"
  typeahead-min-length="4"
/>
```

The input will search into my database the matching entries after user typed the first 4 chars. What happen is that I start to see the matching result, when I type the 5th character, but the search is about the first 4.
I'll explain better: suppose that I have one entry the string 5112.
If I type 5112, no result, but if I type 51123, it return 5112.
Any help?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below..

> The sourceArray expression can use a special $viewValue variable that
>   corresponds to the value entered inside the input.

```
<input type="select" class="form-control pull-right"
  placeholder="Enter IPC or Project Reference" ng-model="systemState.quickSearchTerm"
  uib-typeahead-on-select="selectQuickSearchResult($item)"
  uib-typeahead="result.display for result in quickSearchResults | filter:{display :$viewValue}"
  ng-change="quickSearch()" uib-typeahead-wait-ms="200" ng-model-options="{debounce: 500}"
  typeahead-min-length="4"
/>
```

Comment: I had to change with filter: {display: $item} because with your suggestion didn't work, and still don't work. I still to see my entry after the 5th characted that I press.

Comment: It looks like the selectQuickSearchResult method is using the previous $item, and not the current from the input.

Comment: yep. But we need to use filter as per our scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say search for `query` as soon as user type into a typeahead `input` box. Since we already used `debounce`, it will take care of of waiting for `500ms` before making a call to server.

To make your typeahead to fetch data from `API` each time use `quickSearch($viewValue)` method on `uib-typeahead` directive(check html below) and return `$http` promise from `quickSearch` method each time.

**Html**

```
<input type="select" class="form-control pull-right"
  placeholder="Enter IPC or Project Reference" 
  ng-model="systemState.quickSearchTerm"
  uib-typeahead-on-select="selectQuickSearchResult($item)"
  uib-typeahead="result.display for result in quickSearch($viewValue)"
  typeahead-loading="loadingLocations"
  typeahead-no-results="noResults"
  uib-typeahead-wait-ms="200" ng-model-options="{debounce: 500}"
  typeahead-min-length="4"
/>
<i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
<div ng-show="noResults">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> No Results Found
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
//If you could show me quickSearch method, I can help you to correct this method.
$scope.quickSearch = function (query){
  //I assumed you returned $http to make ajax
  return $http.get('url?query='+query).then(function(){
    return response.data;
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! I removed all the uib-* prefixes, except for the attribute uib-typeahead. And it works.

Comment: Ahh.. which ui-bootstrap version you're using??

Comment: I used the same version of angularjs, the 1.6.6